# Permissions error when editing Windows audit policy programmatically via Winapi

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

**Short Version:**

I am trying to write a C++ program that enables process creation logging on Windows 8. I know this is possible to do using auditpol.exe, but I would like to do it programmatically. My research suggests that the only way to do this is via the Windows API command [AuditSetSystemPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375712%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so I wrote a C++ program (see below) that calls this function. However, that program fails citing a permission problem (error code 1314). I am running Visual Studio as Administrator, and I tried executing the program in a command prompt running as Administrator, but I am still getting the error.

**Long Version:**

The following program takes a [GUID string describing the Process Creation Subcategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd973928.aspx) I want to start auditing and converts it into a GUID struct. It then constructs a [AUDIT_POLICY_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct from the GUID and the ULONG describing the changes I want to make (enable logging on success and failure). Finally I put the struct into an array and call the [AuditSetSystemPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375712%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

```
// Subcategory GUID for Process Creation
string guidstr ("{0CCE922B-69AE-11D9-BED3-505054503030}");

// Construct a GUID object
GUID guid;
HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromString(s2ws (guidstr).c_str(), (LPCLSID)&guid);

// Check if the GUID converted correctly
if (hr == S_OK)
{
    cout << "GUID successfully converted: " << endl;

    // Print english version of the SubCateogory GUID according to the API
    PSTR *output = new PSTR("");
    bool categ_name = AuditLookupSubCategoryName(&guid, output);
    cout << *output << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "GUID failed conversion" << endl;
}

// Create an AUDIT_POLICY_INFORMATION structure describing the desired change
// The AuditCategoryGuid field will be ignored according to documentation
AUDIT_POLICY_INFORMATION audit;
audit.AuditCategoryGuid = (GUID)guid;
audit.AuditSubCategoryGuid = (GUID)guid;

// Turn on auditing for success and failure
audit.AuditingInformation = 0x00000003;

// Create an array of AUDIT_POLICY_INFORMATION change requests
AUDIT_POLICY_INFORMATION arr[1];
arr[0] = audit;

bool policyChanged = TRUE;
policyChanged = AuditSetSystemPolicy(arr, 1);
DWORD last_error = GetLastError();

// Check if the policy change succeeded or not
if (policyChanged == TRUE)
{
    cout << "Successfully set policy" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Failed to set policy. Error:" << endl;     
    cout << last_error << endl;
}
```

I ran this code using Visual Studio Professional 2013 which was started by selecting "Run as Administrator". It results in the following output:

```
GUID successfully converted:
Process Creation
Failed to set policy. Error:
1314
```

The code 1314 means: "[A required privilege is not held by the client.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" According to the AuditSetSystemPolicy documentation: "To successfully call this function, the caller must have SeSecurityPrivilege or have AUDIT_SET_SYSTEM_POLICY access on the Audit security object." I followed the [instructions on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957161.aspx) and verified that Administrator has the right manage auditing and security. For good measure, I also gave my user these rights and rebooted the computer to make sure the changes were applied. I am still getting the error.

I also tried using auditpol.exe to manually turn Process Creation logging off, ran the above code, then used auditpol.exe to verify that the logging was still off. I also pulled up the Event Viewer and manually verified that no logging is taking place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this code and had to correct a few minor issues, but the overall one is you need is to set the "SeSecuritiyPrivilege" on your process object.  Running as Administrator or System will given you authority to set this flag, but you must set it within your code before trying to set the audit level:

```
#include <atlsecurity.h>
...
ATL::CAccessToken processToken;
processToken.GetEffectiveToken(TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES);
processToken.EnablePrivilege("SeSecuritiyPrivilege");
```

Do this BEFORE you try to set the audit level.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. The setting privileges in the code was the piece I was seriously missing.